# Is $ R = \{ \langle A,B\rangle \in P(\mathbb{N}) \times P(\mathbb{N}) : | A \triangle B | < \infty \} $ Equivalence Relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I have the relation $ R = \{ \langle A,B\rangle \in P(\mathbb{N}) \times P(\mathbb{N}) : | A \triangle B | < \infty  \}  $ And I need to show if it is an equivalence relation or not. I was able to show it is reflexive and symmetric but I'm not sure if it is transitive and I have difficulty coming up with the answer ( if it is either symmetric or not ).

**In my attempt for showing transitivity I wrote:**
" Let $  A,B,C \in P(\mathbb{N}) $ be arbitrary. Suppose $  \langle A,B\rangle \in R  $ and $ \langle B , C \rangle \in R $. So it follows that $ | A \triangle B | < \infty $ and $ | B \triangle C | < \infty $ " . But then I got stuck, not knowing how to continue and couldn't come up with a counter-example either for disproving transitivity ( if it $ R $ is indeed non-transitive ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$A \triangle C= (A \triangle B ) \triangle (B \triangle C)$$

Hence R is transitive.

Comment: Very nice, although I'm not familiar with this identity. Do you have another approach?

Comment: Whatever you do, you'll have to use in a way or another this identity. It is quite easy to prove as $\triangle$ is commutative, associative,  $A \triangle A =\emptyset$ and, $A \triangle \emptyset =A$ for any $A$. So $(A \triangle B ) \triangle (B \triangle C) = A \triangle B \triangle B \triangle C = A \triangle \emptyset \triangle C= A \triangle C$.